# Im trying to find Sounds from old bike dynamos

Tags: sound-effects

trying to find Sounds from old bike dynamos.
I have found a few but need more and better variation.
Director can spot fakes easily...

Would be very happy to know where to find some

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Freesound? If I had one rigged up just now I could record it for you, but sadly it is in pieces...